# Clustered index selection with Django

Tags: sql-server, django

I am using django with a SQL Server backend.

Some of my tables will be extremely large. Taking a generalised example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [project_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [value] [float])
```

`[Data].[project_id]` is a foreign key to `[Project].[id]`.

I will have a PK index on `[Task].[id]`, which will also auto-increment, in keeping with django practice.

I will also have a unique index on `[Data].[project_id],[Data].[timestamp]` to prevent duplicate data.

If the majority of my queries will be searching on `[Data].[project_id],[Data].[timestamp]`, is it best to make this index the clustered one, or does the way django interacts with the db mean that the clustering should be left on the primary key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you created the unique clustered index on project_id, timestamp

- A majority of your queries would be fulfilled by a clustered index seek
- There wouldn't appear to be a need for a nonclustered index
- You're already planning on indexing it

Using timestamp, project_id would be a valid argument if you're seeking by a specific date, but most people are querying for dates by a range.  That would allow you to seek for the date range, but then have to scan through that data to find your project_id.  SQL Server will show this as a seek, with timestamp as the Seek Predicate, and project_id as the Predicate.  Your goal is to have as much handled in the Seek Predicate as possible.

However, this is hard to say it's a perfect answer.  The only way you're going to know if this is right is to put it in place, wait a couple days, then check dm_db_index_usage_stats to see if, in fact, most of the uses of this table are actually on project_id, timestamp.  If django is using them differently than you're expecting then it may make sense to change this to be simply ID.